# Swift UI - Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2

Tags: swift, list, image, exc-bad-access

I added system drive icons (NSImage) to my list of drives

Now the app crashes in AppDelegate.swift
on line 13
`class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate {`
with
`Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2, address=0x7ffeef3fff48)`

I know it's the images I am adding because when I replace that with text it's ok

Here is the class where I add the images.

```
import SwiftUI

let workspace = NSWorkspace.init()

struct DriveList: View {
   let drives = SDCardTools.getDrives()!
   var body: some View {
       return List(drives) { drive in
           DriveRow(drive : drive)
       }
   }
}

struct DriveRow: View {
   var drive : Drive
   
   var body: some View {
       HStack {
           DriveIcon(path : drive.path)
               padding(10)
           Text(drive.name)
       }
   }
}

struct DriveIcon : View {
   
   var path: String
   var body: some View {
       Image(nsImage: workspace.icon(forFile: path ))
           .resizable()
           .frame(width: 50, height: 50)
   }
}

struct DriveList_Previews: PreviewProvider {
   static var previews: some View {
       DriveList()
   }
}
```

Thread 1 Queue : com.apple.main-thread (serial)
#0  0x00007fff44382883 in specialized static EnvironmentReadingView._makeView(view:inputs:) ()
#1  0x00007fff44384668 in protocol witness for static View._makeView(view:inputs:) in conformance Image ()
#2  0x00007fff44384610 in protocol witness for static View._makeView(view:inputs:) in conformance Image ()
#3  0x00007fff441c20e9 in TypedUnaryViewGenerator.makeView(in:inputs:id:indirectMap:) ()
#4  0x00007fff441c21f9 in protocol witness for UnaryViewGenerator.makeView(in:inputs:id:indirectMap:) in conformance TypedUnaryViewGenerator ()
#5  0x00007fff441bc9b0 in closure #1 in UnaryElements.makeElements(from:in:inputs:indirectMap:body:) ()
#6  0x00007fff441c4801 in partial apply for closure #1 in UnaryElements.makeElements(from:in:inputs:indirectMap:body:) ()
#7  0x00007fff441bf61b in closure #1 in closure #1 in closure #1 in closure #1 in ModifiedElements.makeElements(from:in:inputs:indirectMap:body:) ()
#8  0x00007fff441ce4c5 in partial apply for closure #1 in closure #1 in closure #1 in closure #1 in ModifiedElements.makeElements(from:in:inputs:indirectMap:body:) ()
#9  0x00007fff445adb15 in specialized static UnaryLayout<>.makeViewImpl(modifier:inputs:body:) ()
#10 0x00007fff4430e339 in specialized static UnaryLayout._makeView(modifier:inputs:body:) ()
#11 0x00007fff4430f101 in protocol witness for static ViewModifier._makeView(modifier:inputs:body:) in conformance _AspectRatioLayout ()
#12 0x00007fff4430eec8 in protocol witness for static ViewModifier._makeView(modifier:inputs:body:) in conformance _FrameLayout ()
#13 0x00007fff441bf2a5 in closure #1 in closure #1 in closure #1 in ModifiedElements.makeElements(from:in:inputs:indirectMap:body:) ()
#14 0x00007fff441ce43d in partial apply for closure #1 in closure #1 in closure #1 in ModifiedElements.makeElements(from:in:inputs:indirectMap:body:) ()
#15 0x00007fff441813ef in closure #2 in static _Layout<>.makeStaticView(root:inputs:list:) ()

Any help you can provide would be gratefully appreciated :)

Comment: It's usually pretty helpful when you also provide some information from the console ;)

Comment: (lldb)  is all there is in the console but have added the thread details to the post

Comment: Could you make it as reproducible example so anyone can test locally? Also, where are those icons located?

Comment: They are system icons for drives. I can upload it to bit bucket so you can take a look

Comment: Thanks @Asperi You can clone it from [code](https://github.com/JamesLeeTrigg/SD-Card-Tool-Kit) so you can take a look

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The bug is very confusing, it is due to inalienable nature of `padding` modifier... and compiler pass it w/o use it as actually modifier, which result in crash.

Here is fix

```
struct DriveRow: View {
    var drive : Drive
    
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            DriveIcon(path : drive.path)
                .padding(10)            // << in this line you missed '.' dot
            Text(drive.name)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks but I have just tried it but still the same issue. But still very good to know :)

Comment: Thanks Asperi I will take a look tonight. Much appreciated :)

Comment: That worked a treat. Thanks Asperi. Guess I was expecting Xcode to pick stuff like that up! I will watch out of that kind of error next time!

Comment: Works for me. I had no dot for onTapGesture and it committed run-time crash not compile error. Unbelievable

Comment: I spent some time with a similar issue, and then I found this. Thank you. DOT? I think Xcode should be yelling me at in the first place.